# Gantt Chart python machine scheduling

Tags: python, matplotlib, job-scheduling, gantt-chart

I'm having some bad time trying to plot a Gantt chart from a data set with python. I have a set of machines that work on different tasks during a time period. I want to make a Gantt chart that shows by the y axis the machines and x axis the time spent on each task.
Each machine should appear just once on the y axis and to make easier to see the tasks I want the same color for each task.

The idea is to check strange things like having the same task being processed by two or more machines together.

Let me show what data set I have with a small example:

```
machine   equipment   start   finish
  m1         e2       date1    date2
  m2         e2       date3    date4
  m1         e1       date5    date6
  m3         e3       date7    date8
  m3         e4       date9    date10
```

I tried to use the [broken_barh](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_barh.html) from matplotlib, but I can't figure out a way to add the data for the plot efficiently. Since I have some thing like 100 machines and 400 tasks.

Here is a picture to show how the output should look like.
[image: Example output]

Current code below:

```
import datetime as dt

machines = set(list(mydata["machine"]))
tasks = set(list(mydata["task"]))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))

yrange = 5 # y width of gantt bar
ymin = 0
orign = min(list(mydata["start"])) # time origin

for i in machines:
    
    stdur = [] # list of tuples (start, duration)
    ymin = index*6 # start y of gantt bar
    
    for index, row in mydata.iterrows():
        
        if row["machine"] == i:
            start = (row["start"] -  orign).total_seconds()/3600
            duration = (row["finish"] -  row["start"]).total_seconds()/3600
        
            stdur.append((start,duration))
        
    ax.broken_barh(stdur,(ymin,yrange))
        
ax.set_xlabel('Time')
ax.set_yticklabels(machines)

plt.show()
```

Comment: What do you mean by efficiency? 100*400 is not much regarding *computational efficiency*.

Comment: actually the data set has something like 2000 rows. I keep looping naively all this to consolidate the lists for different machines and tasks for the plot, it would take a very long time.

Comment: Sounds still feasible. I think there is not much help without you showing your code / giving more information what exactly the problem is (e.g. the preprocessing or final plt.plot() call).

Comment: good point. I'll edit the question

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine passing the entire data to the client and let a JS Gantt do its thing, then the RadiantQ jQuery Gantt Package will be a better option for you. Here is an online demo of something similar:
http://demos.radiantq.com/jQueryGanttDemo/Samples/ServerStatusWithHugeData.htm

This is how it looks:
[image: Server Status Sample]

More on the product here:
http://radiantq.com/products/jquery-gantt-package/jquery-gantt-package-features/